# Merge [document-converter] and [file-converter]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

Do we really need both a [document-converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-converter) tag and [file-converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-converter) tag?
It seem that they almost always could be interchanged.

Comment: Hi Ola! Thank you for all your recent tag edits.  [document-converter] is primarily a subset of [file-converter], so it's probably a good idea for us to either (1) create synonyms, or (2) eliminate [file-converter] and only use more specific conversion tags.  We also have the ambiguous [converter] tag to work on.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that both tags should be kept.

- [document-converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-converter): Microsoft Word format, LibreOffice Writer format, PDF, MarkDown, basic HTML, etc
- [image-conversion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-conversion): JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc
- [file-converter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-converter): Everything else

Each of these tags have dozens of questions, which is a good number.

Some work is needed to correctly classify all of the questions in these tags.